# When do you get extra life in Pac-Man?

Tags: ios, pac-man

In Pac-Man (iPhone version) you get an extra life when you score 10000. When do you get another extra life?

Comment: Worth noting that 10,000 was also true in the original game.

Comment: @tzenes: in fact, if [these](http://www.arcade-museum.com/dipswitch-settings/10816.html) are to be believed, there wasn't even a way for operators to allow you to get another extra life in the original. The only option was to change the score at which you get the one extra life.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the brief description of the game [on Bandai/Namco's site](https://www.bandainamcoent.com/games/pac-man) and in the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pac-man-lite/id293778748), the only extra life mentioned is at 10,000 points.

This would be consistent with the original, as tzenes points out: you got only a single extra life at 10,000 and nothing more after that.

Comment: Brutal.........